# SQL Cross Join getting all dates between date range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with the following structure:

ID: StartDate: EndDate

I want to show all dates in the date range for each ID.

Eg

```
ID = 1: StartDate = 01/01/2018: EndDate = 03/01/2018
ID: 1 01/01/2018
ID: 1 02/01/2018
ID: 1 03/01/2018
```

I think i need to use a cross join but im unsure how to create this for multiple rows?

Comment: Please tell us which database you are using, as the answer would likely depend on that.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Can this be done without a CTE and just using a cross join or cross apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i ended up using a date table and just cross referencing that

```
select *
from Date d
inner join WorkingTable w
       on d.Date >= w.StartDate 
       and d.date < w.EndDate
```

Comment: where is **date table** comes from ...?

Comment: @Pugal, take a look here for an example of creating a date dimension table in your DB https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the CTE for SQL Server, the syntax is somewhat different:

```
declare @startdate date = '2018-01-01';
declare @enddate date = '2018-03-18';

with
  dates as (
    select @startdate as [date]
    union all
    select dateadd(dd, 1, [date]) from dates where [date] < @enddate
  )
select [date] from dates
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select date '2018-01-01' as dte
      union all
      select dte + interval '1 day'
      from dates
      where dte < date '2018-01-03'
     )
select dte
from dates;
```

The exact syntax (whether `recursive` is needed and date functions) differ among databases.  Not all databases support this standard functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Now got this for only one id..,

```
create table #dateTable(id int, col1 date, col2 date)

insert into #dateTable values(1,'05-May-2018','08-May-2018') ,(2,'05-May-2018','05-May-2018') 

select *from #dateTable

with cte(start, ends) as(
select  start = (select top 1 col1 from #dateTable), ends = (select top 1 col2 from #dateTable)
union all
select DATEADD(dd,1,start),ends from cte where start <> ends
)select start from cte option (maxrecursion 10)
```

I'm still working... I update soon...!